# Sharing big chunks of data iOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform, data-sharing

Good morning,

I am a newbie iOS developer and in my app I have 2 users sharing each other, some data using Parse.

On Parse I have implemented the sharing data functionality using push notifications but there are some limitations regarding the data size that can be pushed from one user to another.

I would like to know, if there is some framework in iOS or maybe a third part library, that allows the users to share quickly, big chunks of data, like hd images or really long text messages.

Any suggestion or advice is well appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't include the data in the push itself. Save to data to Parse, send a push to notify the other user, and let the app fetch the data from Parse at the other end. Note that Parse limits uploads to 10 MB, so you might need to use other solutions if you plan on using larger files.

Comment: Cloud Kit is another option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Parse and what capabilities they have.  But to share a large chunk of data you would need a middle man.  And I am using the term "middle man" meaning cloud based.  For example: Google App Engine.  So your "User A" on the app would initiate the uploading of such data to your "Cloud App".  The "Cloud App" would return some sort of key identifying said data.  The app for "User A" would use Parse to just send the key to "User B".  When app for "User B" receives the push notification it would contact the "Cloud App" using the key.  If the key is valid, the app for "User B" will download the large chunk of data.